# Using ggplot in a simple function results in AES errors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need a lot of stacked bar charts in R, so I want to create a very simple function to make it less repetitive.

```
cntl <- function(.data, varname, xlabname, maintitle){
  print (ggplot(.data) + 
           aes(x=varname, fill=progcat) +
           geom_bar(position="fill") +
           scale_fill_manual(name="Control", values=c("#84c96d", "#cecece", "#000000", "#ffcf5e", "#fa6b37")) +
           xlab(xlabname) + ylab("Proportion of Cohort") +
           labs (title=maintitle) +
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)))
}
```

FWIW, `progcat` has 5 levels. Since I need to mess with the order of the bars, when I call the function like this:

```
dset %>%
  arrange (progcat) %>%
  mutate(age=factor(age, levels=c("Up to 60", "61+"))) %>%
  cntl (age, dset$age, "Age", "TEST TITLE")
```

I get the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'age' not found`. If I try to include `inherit.aes=FALSE` in `geom_bar()` after the position argument, it then says `Error: stat_count() requires an x or y aesthetic.` The same code runs fine when hardcoded (without `print` and `.data`). I'm relatively new to `ggplot`; any pointers are super appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ggplot2’s `aes` function works with *unevaluated* arguments. That’s why you can pass column names in a table to it without them being quoted.

To make `aes` work with *variables*, you need to tell it to *evaluate* them. This is easiest using the [curly-curly syntax](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/nse-force.html):

```
cntl <- function(.data, varname, xlabname, maintitle){
  plot(ggplot(.data) + 
           aes(x={{varname}}, fill=progcat) +
           geom_bar(position="fill") +
           scale_fill_manual(name="Control", values=c("#84c96d", "#cecece", "#000000", "#ffcf5e", "#fa6b37")) +
           xlab(xlabname) + ylab("Proportion of Cohort") +
           labs(title=maintitle) +
           theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked (minus the {{}} around `progcat` - only `varname` is being evaluated).